# How does IntelliJ IDEA store dependency on PostgreSQL JDBC with Maven without altering pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jdbc, pg-jdbc

I created Maven project with IntelliJ IDEA, and followed [this](https://www.sohamkamani.com/java/jdbc-postgresql/) tutorial on how to connect PostgreSQL JDBC with Java. But, instead of changing `pom.xml` file, I went to `Project Structure` → `Libraries`, where I've added `postgresql-42.6.0.jar`.

Everything works fine, but I'm curious how is this dependency stored, since `pom.xml` file does not include `postgresql-42.6.0.jar`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Mixing Maven and IntelliJ libraries is usually not advisable. Add everything in the POM, this is better.

Answer (score 0):

By default `.m2/repository` from the user's home directory is used. To change it you can select the library destination while downloading:

[image]

In general, it is not recommended to manage dependencies through `Project Structure` → `Libraries` if build system like Maven/Gradle is used in the project because these settings might be lost after the project re-import triggered by the IDE Maven plugin.

Consider adding this dependency to the `pom.xml` directly.

Comment: I ca't find it inside `.m2/repository`. See https://pastebin.com/mLLk28Tq

Comment: Check `Project Structure` → `Libraries` settings. An absolute path to the library should be mentioned here. E.g., https://prnt.sc/H8bDfhghY9GY

Comment: I've added manually the path for `postgresql-42.6.0.jar`, i.e. it's `C:\libs\postgresql-42.6.0.jar.`

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ load the dependency based on your pom.xml and add it to the `Libraries` automatically.

Manually adding jars to the Libraries will work. Still, it will only work in the machine where the jar is added, and every time the project is loaded into another machine or reloaded in the same machine, the jar has to be added manually.

You must use Maven for dependency management so this manual action can be avoided. And your project will work in all places, including other IDEs and CI servers.

If you want to add the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to your project, add the following dependency in your pom.xml in the dependencies section.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So your final pom.xml will be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```